# Run a shell script using java program along with parameters

Tags: java, runtime

I am trying to run a shell script from my java application and not been able to pass the context params that are required for my script to run.

Below is the command that works when I direct call the file on cmd

```
MytestFile.sh --context_param db_host="localhost" --context_param db_name="test_db" --context_param data_api="https://test-api-dev-view.cloud.my.com/meta-info" --context_param api_body_path="C:\\MyTest\\4009\\New\\postRequestSmart.txt" --context_param service_customer="me" --context_param service_url="https://test-view.cloud.my.com/" --context_param file_path="C:\\Test\\4009\New\\fileloc" --context_param processedDirectory="C:\\Test\\4009\\New\\PD"
```

Now I am trying to call the same using java Runtime and i am passing the context param as strArray

Updated :

```
public class App2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] strArray = new String[]{ "--context_param db_host=localhost"
                , "--context_param db_name=test_db"
                , "--context_param data_api=https://test-api-dev-view.cloud.my.com/meta-info"
                , "--context_param api_body_path=C:\\MyTest\\4009\\New\\postRequestSmart.txt"
                , "--context_param service_customer=me"
                , "--context_param service_url=https://https://test-view.cloud.my.com/"
                , "--context_param file_path=C:\\Test\\4009\New\\fileloc"
                , "--context_param processedDirectory=C:\\Test\\4009\\New\\PD"}

              try { 
                 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start MytestFile.sh", strArray); 
              } catch (IOException e) { 
                 e.printStackTrace(); 
              }

    }

}
```

Approach 2 : Using Process builder

```
package com.test.shell;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Map;


public class App2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        

        String[] strArray = new String[]{ "--context_param db_host=localhost"
                , "--context_param db_name=test_db"
                , "--context_param data_api=https://test-api-dev-view.cloud.my.com/meta-info"
                , "--context_param api_body_path=C:\\MyTest\\4009\\New\\postRequestSmart.txt"
                , "--context_param service_customer=me"
                , "--context_param service_url=https://https://test-view.cloud.my.com/"
                , "--context_param file_path=C:\\Test\\4009\New\\fileloc"
                , "--context_param processedDirectory=C:\\Test\\4009\\New\\PD"}
        

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "MytestFile.bat");
        Process p = pb.start();

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String output;
        while ((output = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }

}
```

This is invoking my batch/sh file but can someone please help as to how to pass parameters into this ProcessBuilder ?

I feel I am not passing the parameters correctly.

Please let me know where I need to correct this.

TIA

Comment: you hand't close your parenthese in try block, also you're not passing you strArray as method parameter, rather you are sending raw String; if you want to parematrize "cmd /c start MytestFile.sh" with strArray try something like this: `String.format("cmd %s start MytestFile.sh", strArray)`

Comment: also check your input `"... --context_param db_name=test_db--context_param data_api= ..."` at least missing a space (not to speak from closing quote after `service_customer=me` and more places)

Comment: @user15793316 sorry it was a typo , i have corrected it

Comment: PawełSosnowski I modified it to a proper string array , but it still doesnt recognize.
I updated the code in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing the arguments after the command in one array, and split the arguments to individual parameters at the spaces:

```
    String[] cmd = new String[]{ 
        "MytestFile.bat"
            , "--context_param"
            , "db_host=localhost"
            ...
            , "--context_param"
            , "file_path=C:\\Test\\4009\New\\fileloc"
            , "--context_param"
            ,"processedDirectory=C:\\Test\\4009\\New\\PD"}
    

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
```

It does not work in your first example as the `Runtime.exec(String,String[])` method, the second argument is environment **not** arguments to the script.